# Inline PHP If statement returns url outside of background-image style

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, inline

Not sure where I've gone wrong? Researching this has provided me with not solutions.

```
<?php echo ( has_post_thumbnail() ? 'background-image: url('. the_post_thumbnail_url() .');' : 'height: auto;' ); ?>
```

This is what I see returned in the browser.

```
<div class="image" style="//192.168.50.4:3000/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/rns-placeholder.pngbackground-image: url();">
```

Comment: Can you post the code prior to your `<?php echo` as this may help.

Comment: The below answer works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_post_thumbnail_url()` outputs value, not **returns** it.

You need to use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` instead:

```
<?php echo ( has_post_thumbnail() ? 'background-image: url('. get_the_post_thumbnail_url() .');' : 'height: auto;' ); ?>
```

Comment: If answer helps to solve your problem - __accept__ and optionally upvote it.